# Can I call a cursor using variable name?

Tags: oracle, plsql

> I  want to call a cursor based on an input parameter. 'dept' is the input from command line. I am getting PLS-00456 : not a cursor error. Is there a way to call driving_query_int cursor using cursor_name as variable?

```
declare
dept            varchar(8):= 'int';
cursor_name     varchar(20):= 'driving_query_'||dept;

cursor driving_query_int is 
select * from <table>;

begin
open cursor_name;
end;
```

Comment: your cursor name is driving_query_int not cursor_name, so it should be: open driving_query_int

Comment: Yes, But I am going to create one more cursor and want to choose from two cursors depending on the value of dept. e.g. if dept is shared, then cursor_name will be driving_query_shared and if I use the same variable cursor_name for both these cursors - driving_query_int and driving_query_shared, I will be able to call multiple cursors with one variable name, if that makes sense

Comment: then use a if:
if condition_shared then
  open cursor_name_shared;
else
   open cursor_name;
end if;

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to give a dynamic name to you cursor.

Comment: I tried doing that then the next twist is that when you use fetch statement, you cannot write     if dept = 'int' fetch driving_query_int into something; else fetch driving_query_shared into something. Then I would have to write the same if else logic for closing the cursor. I am avoiding that by creating a variable name. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok but why the dynamic cursor name in the first place, instead of declaring the query when you declare the cursor, just do:
declare cursor_name SYS_REFCUSOR;

then do you test:
if dept = 'int' then
 open cursor_name for 'select blablabla from table where...';
else
 open cursor_name for 'select tototo from other_table where...';
end if;

Comment: Alright, I will try that too. I tried using cursor variable like you described but I was getting issues in the sql query part of it. The part where you say sql_stmt := 'select * form whatever' and then open cursor_name for stmt. But I will try it this way. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Using a dynamic cursor name is not necessary, use this instead:

```
declare
    dept            varchar(8):= 'int';
    cursor_name     SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_number number;
begin

    if dept='int' then
        open cursor_name for 'select 1 from dual';
    else
        open cursor_name for 'select 2 from dual';
    end if;

    loop
        fetch cursor_name into v_number;
        exit when cursor_name%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_number);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

if dept equals to "int" then 1 will be displayed, else 2 will be displayed.
You understand the logic, juste replace the statements by the one you need and code the logic inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dont go with this architechture. Here you dont need dynamic sql. Since you have all the cursor defined as per the name. Try using IF-ELSE construct to open cursor. If the only motive behind this cursor is to show data then i uggest use ref cursor. Hope below snippet helps.

```
var lv_cur refcursor;
DECLARE
  dept        VARCHAR(8) := 'int';
  CURSOR_NAME VARCHAR(20):= 'driving_query_'||DEPT;
BEGIN
  IF CURSOR_NAME                  = 'driving_query_int' THEN
    OPEN :LV_CUR FOR SELECT * FROM <TABLE1>;
  ELSIF CURSOR_NAME              = 'something' THEN
    OPEN :LV_CUR FOR SELECT * FROM <TABLE2>;
    --Add on the if conditons
  END IF;
END;
/

print lv_cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

can your expand your scenario? is this solved?

try this :

```
var cur_nm refcursor;
c1 cur_nm;
DECLARE
  dept        VARCHAR(8) := 'int';
  CURSOR_NAME VARCHAR(20):= 'driving_query_'||DEPT;
BEGIN
  IF CUR_NAME                  = 'ur condition' THEN
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT * FROM  tbl;
  ELSIF CUR_NAME              = 'ur condition' THEN
    OPEN c1 FOR SELECT * FROM tbl;
    --Add on the if conditons
  END IF;
fetch blablabla into ur var;
END;
/
```